# How to import MySQL RAW Database files without connection error

Tags: mysql, database, import, server, export

unfortunately I did not create a 'dump' file or sql file with the backup (Data Export) process on MySQL Workbench 8.0.26.

When I copy the old database files to the new Data directory, the server fails to start with the message:

```
Could not connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (code 2003)
```

Tried to do a clean install of MySQL Server 8.0.26 and Workbench 8.0.14 on Windows Web Server 2008 R2. Which after that install the MySQL Server works fine. But then when I stop the server and copy the old Database files into the new Data directory, the MySQL Server fails to start after that. Although I have read that this is not the usual way to 'backup' and restore a MySQL Database, though I wasn't aware of that before.

Is there any way to convert the old Database files into a 'dump' file outside of MySQL Workbench?

Thank you.

Comment: [dba.se] is the place to ask, but importing a MySQL database file (as opposed to an exported file) is not usually straightforward, and may not work at all.

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular, For cold physical backup, same mysql version and OS between source and target server, would the migration still fail?